# Win32 edit control default text

Tags: c, winapi

(NB: This is probably more of a programming style / architecture question)

When the main window is created (but not yet shown), my window procedure receives WM_CREATE; this is where I call CreateWindow for the edit control:

```
    case WM_CREATE:
        hwndEdit = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, TEXT("edit"), L"Default text",
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_LEFT | ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
        10, 10, 150, 24, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_EDIT,
        hInst, NULL);
        break;
```

and as expected "Default text" shows up in the edit control.

I know I can also use SendMessage or SetWindowText.

So, I have three API calls to do what I want - which one should I be using?

best,
Chris

Comment: *If the target window is owned by the current process, SetWindowText causes a WM_SETTEXT message to be sent to the specified window or control* - so *SetWindowText* is only thin shell over *WM_SETTEXT* in your case. and if text known at window creation time - the best just set it in call *CreateWindowEx* - for what additional *SendMessage* or *SetWindowText* ?

Comment: I'm thinking about unwanted side-effects that one of these methods might have, but which I don't know about yet. If they are equally OK to use, then I will stick with my solution.

Comment: If there is a solution that can be implemented with a single API call, why look for other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is easy and convenient to set the text in `CreateWindowEx`, then do so.

If, for some reason, it is not convenient, then use `SetWindowText`.

In this case you probably don't want to use `L"Default Text"` as the default text in `CreateWindowEx`.

Since `lpWindowName` is optional, you may pass `NULL` to leave it blank.

Alternatively, you might use something which makes more sense for your application, such as `L"(Loading...)"`.